# Send Log Error Codes

Tags: marketing-cloud, error, triggered-send

I have recently created a send log and can see error codes

> 22,23 and 24

. I would like to know what these represent, as I have searched for documentation and cannot seem to find anything on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As usual, the documentation is very well hidden ([here](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/email_messages/email_send_error_codes/)).

It appears:

> **22** (Data Extension Insert Failed) - Failed to insert a row into the
>   Triggered Send data extension.
>   **23** (Domain Exclusion) - The subscriber was excluded by a domain exclusion list.
>   **24** (List Detective Exclusion) - The subscriber was excluded by List Detective.

Below is a screen grab of the chart, in case the link dies like they are prone to do...

[image: Email Send Error Codes]

Comment: Can it be expected to see all of these error codes reported on the send log?