# How to prevent the same email being sent to the same subscriber twice in the same day?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, exclusion-script, suppressionlist

I'm working in an environment where the expectations of the users sending emails out of Marketing Cloud need to be kept to a minimum. So, I need to setup a solution for preventing them from sending the same email to the same person twice in the same day that doesn't require them to do anything.

The out-of-the-box "de-duplicate email address" checkbox in the send wizard won't work because they're doing multiple sends. I can't wait around for a batch process, since the duplicate sends are occurring within minutes of each other. So, I have to go with a script that runs at send time. But I can't use an Exclusion script, because the users sending the email can't be depended on to use it.

The solution I've come up with is an AMPscript that I'm going to insert into the header of the standard template. The script will perform a lookup to a data extension with a one-day retention policy at time of send, matching on the email address of the recipient and the name of the email in Email Studio. If it finds an entry with the same email address and email name, it'll "raise error" and skip that subscriber. If it doesn't match an entry, it'll write one to the same data extension.

Just wondering if there are any holes in my approach or if someone thinks there's a better way to do this.

```vb
%%[
VAR @RecipientEmail, @EmailName, @LookupSend, @Now, @CheckForPriorSend

SET @RecipientEmail = emailaddr
SET @EmailName = emailname_
SET @Now = Now()


IF _IsTestSend == FLASE AND _messagecontext == "SEND" THEN
    SET @LookupSend = LOOKUPROWS("SameDaySuppression","RecipientEmail",@RecipientEmail,"EmailName",@EmailName)
    SET @CheckForPriorSend = ROWCOUNT(@LookupSend)

    IF @CheckForPriorSend == 0 THEN
        InsertDE("SameDaySuppression","RecipientEmail",@RecipientEmail,"EmailName",@EmailName,"SendDateTime",@Now)
    ELSE
            SET @InsertDEVar = InsertDE("SameDaySuppressedLog","RecipientEmail",@RecipientEmail,"EmailName",@EmailName,"SendDateTime",@Now)
            /* The data will only be preserved after the RaiseError if you include the 'SET' statement in the line above. */
            RaiseError("Duplicate send",true,"This email was already sent to this address today",425,"1")
    ENDIF
ELSE
ENDIF

]%%
```

One thing I'm specifically debating is should I depend on the retention policy or should I use a DATEDIFF to check for sends that occurred in the same day. This is what that would look like...

```vb
%%[
VAR @RecipientEmail, @EmailName, @LookupSend, @Now, @CheckForPriorSend

SET @RecipientEmail = emailaddr
SET @EmailName = emailname_
SET @Now = Now()
SET @NumRowsToReturn = 10
SET @IsTestSend = _IsTestSend
SET @messagecontext = _messagecontext

IF @IsTestSend == FALSE AND @messagecontext == "SEND" THEN
    SET @LookupSend = LookupOrderedRows("SameDaySuppression",@NumRowsToReturn,"SendDateTime desc","RecipientEmail",@RecipientEmail,"EmailName",@EmailName)
    SET @CheckForPriorSend = ROWCOUNT(@LookupSend)

    IF @CheckForPriorSend == 0 THEN
        InsertDE("SameDaySuppression","RecipientEmail",@RecipientEmail,"EmailName",@EmailName,"SendDateTime",@Now)
    ELSE
        @LastSendRow = Row(@LookupSend,1)
        @LastSendDateTime = Field(@LastSendRow,"LastSendRow")

        IF DATEDIFF(@LastSendDateTime,@Now,"D") == 0 THEN
            SET @InsertDEVar = InsertDE("SameDaySuppressedLog","RecipientEmail",@RecipientEmail,"EmailName",@EmailName,"SendDateTime",@Now) 
/* The data will only be preserved after the RaiseError if you include the 'SET' statement in the line above. */
            RaiseError("Duplicate send",true,"This email was already sent to this address today",425,1)
        ELSE
            InsertDE("SameDaySuppression","RecipientEmail",@RecipientEmail,"EmailName",@EmailName,"SendDateTime",@Now)
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
ELSE
ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: Why not use the sendlog and lookuporderedrows in an exclusion script? Raiseerror still counts as a send.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I believe OP needs something that would work without any effort from the person responsible for sending the email, thus RaiseError embedded automatically in all email templates.

Comment: @Will I wouldn’t depend on retention - it would be better to use a combination of a SendLog (to keep info about sent emails) and a second DE, a “suppression log”, where you’d keep info about all suppressed emails - trust me you’ll need it when you get questions from your end users. So I’d add one more line to your script - an InsertDE function before the RaiseError, to log all suppressions.

Comment: Thanks @zuzannamj. You were spot on in your response to Adam: I can't rely on the users to add the exclusion script or else that's the route I'd go.

I liked your idea about logging instances where the email was suppressed & added it to the script, but I think that functionality is broken globally for RaiseError(). I found two articles on Stackexchange, one from just 7 months ago, where people were saying that even SFMC support couldn't explain why their data extension entries weren't being retained.  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241143/raiseerror-additional-arguments